How to add data (35 or 35 participants?)
I already mentioned the number "35" refers to the number of people participating in martial arts. However, I feel that "35" doesn't read well. '35 participants' reads better. This is just my feeling. Should I add the word "participants" after "35"?

The number of people participating in martial arts showed very small
changes, hovering around the 35 participants mark. (I wrote the sentence.)



"... hovering around 35" works for me (no the).

"the 35 participants mark" is needlessly wordy.

@TimR, what do you suggest? hovering around 35 or hovering around the 35 mark?

As there is no such mark, "was about 35" or "remained fairly constant over the 20-year period, at around 35 participants".

@TimR - I'm pretty sure that the 'mark' in 'hovering around the XX mark' can be a purely notional one, although if it was in text accompanying an actual chart, I agree it would be potentially confusing.

@MichaelHarvey "The 35 participants mark" refers to one of the chart's visual properties. In discussions of  the underlyhing data a chart presents, one doesn't typically refer to the chart's visual properties but to the data.  We would say "Martial arts averaged 35 participants over the 20-year period examined" not "Martial arts participation remained near the 35 participants tick mark."  It would be like saying of a character in a play, "Many of Hamlet's lines end with a question mark."

A "mark" may or may not be literally marked, but it should be significant in some way. Say the study needs at least 35 martial arts participants to draw statistically significant conclusions—that's an important number. But in the question, "mark" is misused.

Hovering around 35 is fine.
We may also consider this version:
The number of martial arts participants is quite consistent over the years, at (or hovering) around 35.

Sample: The number of people participating in martial arts showed very small changes, hovering around the 35 participants mark. (I wrote the sentence.)
Generally, we'd use:
The number of people participating in martial arts changed little, hovering around the 35-participant mark. OR hovering around thirty five.
